# JQuery find() opposite

Tags: jquery, find, parent, closest

I want to find the next form-element, starting from input-object inside.
Find() is a great function to find child objects. But what about the opposite Way to find in parent?

```
<form id="grabbMe">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
            <div><input type="text" value="test"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    $('input').findUp('form').attr('id')
</script>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use jQuery's closest() function to do this.

```
$('input').closest('form').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 8):

#### The opposite of `find()` is `parents()`.

`closest()` isn't quite an opposite to `find()`, although depending on what you're trying to do, it may work for you.

the `find()` function finds **all** occurances of the selector within the descendants of the element you specify.

`closest()` only finds the first occurrence of the selector, going upward through the ancestors of the specified element.

So the correct opposite to `find()` would be `parents()`, which will find **all** ancestors of your element that match the specified selector.